# Attaching files on Lotus Notes using VBA

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I am trying to insert an attachment file into a Lotus Notes document using VBA. Here is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
Dim Anotesuiworkspace as Object

Dim NUIdoc As Object

Dim rtitem As Object

Dim FileName As String
```

This creates a new Document and opens it on Lotus Notes

```
Set Anotesuiworkspace = CreateObject("Notes.Notesuiworkspace")
Set NUIdoc = Anotesuiworkspace.composeDocument("", "", "Dash 8 request")
```

Random File location

```
FileName = "C:\Users\k0600292\Desktop\Vacation Tracker\Andy Vacation.xlsx"

'$FILE is the name of the Field I am looking to attach the document into
'Get an error while running the next line saying "Object doesnt support this property or method"

Set rtitem = NUIdoc.GetFirstItem("$FILE")

Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", FileName)

End Sub
```

Any recommendations/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) You do not embed/attach the file into $FILE. You attach it to a Rich-Text field on the form. The field $FILE is a system field.
2) You can only attach files using the back-end classes. EmbedObject() is a method of the NotesDocument class, not of the NotesUIDocument,

Your code should look something like this:

```
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("AttachmentRTField")
Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", filename)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

Comment: And if "AttachmentRTField" doesn't exist, change the method call to CreateRichTextItem("AttachmentRTField") (or whatever name you want to give the field.

Comment: 1) The code provided by @Karl-Henry Martinsson assumably requires me to replace "AttachmentRTField" with the Rich-Text Field name associated with the respective field. However, since I did not create the form, I am uncertain regarding the exact name of the field, so is there a way to determine the name alloted to the rich-text field?

Comment: 2) @Duston , I tried to replace doc.GetFirstItem("AttachmentRTField") with doc.CreateRichTextItem("AttachmentRTField")  
but I got a mismatch error on the last line of code (embedobject).

Comment: What type of variable is object?  EmbedObject returns a NotesEmbeddedObject

Comment: PLEASE use standard item names as long as you have no reason to not use them. The „Body“ of any standard- doxument within Notes is called „Body“ (mails, calendar entries, Contacts, Journal Entries....). And this item usually contains the attachments as well. It is best practice to use the default item names (Subject, Categories, SendTo, CopyTo, BlindCopyTo, From, just to name some of them)

Comment: @Duston Object is set as a NotesEmbeddedObject which returns the mismatch error. However, changing it to just an Object variable results in no error.  Yet the Attachment Field on my form is empty. So the question I have is don't we have to link the doc.CreateRichTextItem("AttachmentRTField") to the actual Attachment field on my form somehow?

Comment: Did you call doc.save() after you called EmbedObject?

Comment: Yes, I did. Since it is a form with multiple fields, how can I specify the exact field I would like the attachment to be inserted in?

Comment: @ashley - It will be inserted in the field you specify. First you get a NotesRichTextItem object, corresponding to the field you want to insert the attachment into, then you use the EmbedObject method to actually attach the file.

Comment: On your question 1) above, how to get the field name, you can get it in a couple of ways. You can open the form used for the document in Domino Designer and look at it there, or you can right-click on a document in the Notes client and look at the properties The fields are listed in the second tab, together with the values for each field in the selected document.